# Ionic2 proxyUrl does not work on device

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

While running the app on device it does not get the api url 
it does not fetch the url

I have used following coding

```
{
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": 'api url here'
    }
  ]
}
```

Please give any suggustions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy service is meant for testing in the browser to avoid the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error when using an external API. But this is not a problem on devices and therefor there is no need for this proxy service. So, on devices use direct calls to your API url in stead of calls to `http://localhost:8100`.

If you want to test on both a device and browser, just check if Cordova is available (and so you're on a device) and then define which URL to use. Something like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import ...

@Injectable()
export class AccessService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private apiUrl = '/v1/';

    constructor(private http: Http,
                public platform: Platform) {

        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {                // <<< is Cordova available?
            this.apiUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/';
        }
    }

    login(username: string, password: string): Promise<string> {
        let postParams = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };

        return this.http
            .post(this.apiUrl + 'login', postParams, this.headers)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().devicetoken as string)
            .catch(this.handleError);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: then how can i set a api url in config

Comment: Anywhere you want: in your component, in an access service or in a constant. I edited my answer with a more extended example (also changed it to Ionic 2). Hopefully this gives you a better idea. I just made up the example and this is not tested. Just to give you an idea.

Comment: A more advanced way is use automation tools like gradle